# Arquivos .css devem ficar na pasta /public ou /resources?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Gostaria de saber porque o Laravel 8 é buildado com a pasta `/css` dentro de `/resources` e não dentro de `/public`, assim como consta na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-public-directory)?

| Chamada do arquivo css | Diretório do arquivo css | resultado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `<link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` | resources/css/main.css | Laravel não encontra a pasta e não carrega o arquivo css. |
| `<link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` | public/css/main.css | Tudo acontece perfeitamente. |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O public diretório contém o index.phparquivo, que é o ponto de entrada para todas as solicitações que entram em seu aplicativo e configura o carregamento automático. Este diretório também hospeda seus **ativos**, como imagens, JavaScript e **CSS**.

O resource diretório contém suas visualizações , bem como seus **recursos brutos** e não compilados, como CSS ou JavaScript. Este diretório também contém todos os seus arquivos de idioma.

Seus arquivos .css devem ficar ,por exemplo, em uma pasta assets dentro de Public.

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode minificar seus assets seguindo a própria documentação do Laravel com Laravel Mix. Eles permaneceram na sua pasta resources e serão minificados para a pasta public.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css');
```

Linka para documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix